# Is there a way to repeat the first two rows of a table as a header on each page in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-word-2010

I want to repeat the first two rows of the table as the table header on each page of a Word document.

I can repeat the **first row** by checking "Repeat row as table header" in the Table properties but I don't know how to make the **top two rows** repeat. Any ideas?

Comment: I have stupid obsorvation, but isn't tasks like this better suited to Excel? Why do you need to print it with word?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I can repeat the **first row** by checking "Repeat row as table header" in the Table properties but I don't know how to make the **top two rows** repeat. Any ideas?

You *can* set the top two rows to repeat as header. You just have to select them at the same time when changing the option so that they both to repeat together.

I don't have Word 2007 or 2010 handy to take screenshots of, so these are showing 2003, but the process is the same in all three.

First select *both rows at the same time*, then access table properties:

[image]

Now you can set both rows to repeat as a header together:

[image]

And both these rows will now repeat, job done:

[image]

Comment: FYI, in Word 2013 you don't even need to select the rows at the same. Click on the first row and activate `Repeat row as table header`. Click on the second row and do the same. Repeat as often as needed. Of course the headers must be consecutive starting with the first row (e.g. row 3 can't be a header while row 2 isn't.).